# The ' this ' keyword in abstract classes

Tags: c#, this, abstract-class

I am slightly confused towards why I am able to use the 'this' in abstract classes.

I am making a very very simple object oriented role playing game. I have a base/super class called `Items`. I then have two types of items, equiptable and non-equiptable.

```
interface IEquiptable
{
    void equiptItem(Player p);
    void unequiptItem(Player p);
}
```

Theres the interface for equiptable items.

Next, I have an abstract class called `Weapons`:

```
abstract class Weapons : Items, IEquiptable 
{
    public double powerOfWeapon { get; set; }
    public double powerNeededToUse { get; set; }


    public void equiptItem(Player p)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(this); 
        p.weapon = this;
    }

    public void unequiptItem(Player p)
    {
        //UNTESTED METHOD
        p.weapon = new Swords("Fists", 1, 1);
    }

}
```

This extends the base class of `Items` (this class only contains a name for the item at the moment, so not worth show) and implements the interface 'IEquiptable'.

Finally I have a class called `Swords`

```
class Swords : Weapons
{

    public Swords(string name, double powerOfS, double powerToU)
    {
        base.name = name;
        powerOfWeapon = powerOfS;
        powerNeededToUse = powerToU;
    }

}
```

This extends Weapons and provides a constructor for the sword.

Here is some of my `Player` class

```
class Player
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double life { get; set; }
    public double power { get; set; }
    public Weapons weapon { get; set; } // Currently held weapon

    private List<Items> items; //This is being used to represent a 'backpack' any item obtained will be added here.
```

To eqipt a weapon I am using this method: (in my player class)

```
public void equiptWeapon()
    {
        Weapons tempWep = items.OfType<Weapons>().FirstOrDefault();
        if (tempWep != null)
        {
            tempWep.equiptItem(this);        
        } 
    }
```

I don't understand why this works. tempWep is being given the value of the first Weapon in the list. But then it is calling the method `equiptItem()` which is being implemented in by abstract class and then 'this' is being assigned, which I cannot follow how it doesn't throw an error for not being to initialize `Weapons`

Hopefully you can understand what I mean.

Thanks.

Comment: Weapons don't equip themselves. The `Person` should have the `Equip` method. Regardless of that, an abstract class, although you can't instantiate it directly, does after all represent an object - hence `this`.

Comment: Just to clarify - what you're doing here is telling the person to equip a weapon, and the person does that by telling the weapon to equip itself on that person, and then the weapon actually equips itself on the person. That's PingPong#.

Comment: Maybe this will help. Mentally imagine every method that uses "this" is now a *static* method. Now add a formal parameter to that method called `_this`. Mentally replace every `this` with `_this`.  For properties, imagine they are static methods `static int get_Color(Shape _this) { return _this.color; }` and similarly for setters. In a world where every method is static and no one uses `this`, do you have any objection?  Because *that's basically how it works*. `this` is just a convention that there's a hidden formal parameter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Language constraints mean you cannot create an abstract class directly, however it is totally possible to have an instance of it - you simply create an instance of a derived class and then cast it down to the abstract class. An abstract class can also have implementation in it, so the usage of the keyword `this` is perfectly normal and acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [Microsoft on Abstract Keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf985hc5%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).
It's meant to work like that. Just Because the object itself can not be instantiated does not mean it will never be instantiated. As a matter of fact your **guaranteed** to have an implementing class before you can possibly reach the `this` keyword in your code. Thus it's safe. ( When you request a `Weapon` from your `Item` list, that `Weapon` had to have already been instantiated in your code. Presumably to a `Swords` or the like. Otherwise you could never access it to store it in the list and so on )

Finally I will note that the way you are using the `Weapon` class can be slightly confusing. So a short analogy in on point. Think about it this way. Just because the thought, swing a weapon, means nothing without a actual weapon in hand, does not mean that if you are holding a weapon in hand; it has can not refer to that weapon.

Hope it's a bit clearer now.